# Python extracting/editing all constants involved in a function via AST?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Let's say I have the following code:

```
def f(x, y, n = 1):
    k = 10
    z = x**n + y**n + k
    return z

def g(x):
    alpha = 10
    return f(x, alpha)
```

I would like to analyze `g` to extract from it all constants involved in returning its output: `alpha`, `n`, and `k`. Is it possible to do this in python, perhaps by using the `ast` library?

Further, if the above is possible, is it then possible to edit some of those constants:

`h = create_new_function(g, g.alpha = 25, f.k = 50)`

It would be quite something if this were possible!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.AST) and 
[inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) modules to do this task

1. Use `inspect.getsource` to get the source of the function where you want to extract the variables.
2. Parse the function source code to an ast node using `ast.compile`
3. Go through the child nodes inside the body of the root node and find instances of the class `ast.Assign`.
4. For each assignation, fetch the left & right operands using the attributes `targets` and `value` of such nodes

You can do something like this (I assume all values in the assignations are numbers):

```py
import ast
from inspect import getsource
from operator import attrgetter

# This is the function we want to know its variables
def foo():
    a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
    d = 0

# Get the code and parse it to an ast node
code = getsource(foo)
root = ast.parse(code)

# Get all assignations
assigns = root.body[0].body


for assign in assigns:
    # For each assignation...

    # Find left operands on the assignation
    vars = []
    for target in assign.targets:
        if isinstance(target, ast.Tuple):
            vars.extend(target.elts)
        else:
            vars.append(target)

    # Get operand names
    varnames = list(map(attrgetter('id'), vars))


    # Also get right operands (we assume are all numbers)
    if isinstance(assign.value, ast.Tuple):
        values = list(map(attrgetter('n'), assign.value.elts))
    else:
        values = (assign.value.n,)

    # Print info
    print(', '.join(varnames) + ' = ' + ', '.join(map(str, values)))
```

The output of the code above is:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
d = 0
```